# fast install package during development with multiarch

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I'm working on a package "xyz" that uses Rcpp with several cpp files. 
When I'm only updating the R code, I would like to run `R CMD INSTALL xyz` on the package directory without having to recompile all the shared libraries that haven't changed. That works fine if I specify the `--no-multiarch` flag: the source directory `src` gets populated the first time with the compiled objects, and if the sources don't change they are re-used the next time. With multiarch on, however, R decides to make two copies of `src`, `src-i386` and `src-x86_64`. It seems to confuse `R CMD INSTALL` which *always* re-runs all the compilation. Is there any workaround?

(I'm aware that there are alternative ways, e.g. `devtools::load_all`, but I'd rather stick to `R CM INSTALL` if possible).

The platform is MacOS 10.7, and I have the latest version of R.

Comment: I am very interested in answers you might get.

Answer (score 4):

I have a partial answer for you. One *really easy* for speed-up is provided by using ccache which you can enable for all R compilation (e.g. via `R CMD whatever` thereby also getting `inline`, `attributes`, `RStudio` use, ...) globally through `.R/Makevars`:

```
edd@max:~$ tail -10 .R/Makevars

VER=4.6
CC=ccache gcc-$(VER)
CXX=ccache g++-$(VER)
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++-$(VER)
FC=ccache gfortran
F77=ccache gfortran
MAKE=make -j8

edd@max:~$
```

It takes care of all caching of compilation units.

Now, that does not "explicitly" address the `--no-multiarch` aspect which I don;t play much with that as we are still mostly 'single arch' on Linux. This will change, eventually, but hasn't yet.  Yet I suspect but by letting the compiler decide the caching you too will get the net effect.

Other aspects can be controlled too, eg `~/.R/check.Renviron` can be used to turn certain tests on or off.  I tend to keep'em all on -- better to waste a few seconds here than to get a nastygram from Vienna.

Comment: thanks – i'll do some homework to figure out what these things are and how they work on Mac, and I'll report back here